# angular 4 httpGet withCredentials and header conflict

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

for sending cookie to server I must use { withCredentials: true } in options parameter,But When I use

```
    this.http.get(this.accountUrl + 'ExternalLoginConfirmation', { 
    withCredentials: true })
```

I get the following error :

```
    Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 
    value 
    of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be 
    the 
    wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 
    'http://localhost:4202' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials 
    mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the 
    withCredentials attribute.
```

Odd thing : There isn't any error when I call this url by browser

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS error ,
Try adding Cors chrome extension browser and add your url in it this error will go away.
Or for permanent resolution
Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24446980/4808975

Comment: Thanks! It works with `builder.AllowAnyOrigin()          .AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();` in server side